# Rails- How can I create view for nasted tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get data like this in the show.html.erb , but it doesn't work.
How can I get data from spot table?

here is the code.

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @planaction.each do |action| %>

        <hr>
        <%= action.spot.name %>
        <%= action.spot.description %>
        <hr>

        <%= action.title %>
        <%= action.experience %>

<% end %>
```

**plan.rb**

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :plan_actions

end
```

**plan_action.rb**

```
class PlanAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :spot
end
```

**spot.rb**

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan_action
end
```

**plan_actions_controller.erb**

```
class PlanPagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    @planaction = @plan.plan_actions
  end
end
```

**and error message here**

*undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass*

and here is migration file for spot table.

```
    class CreateSpots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spots do |t|
      t.integer :spot_id
      t.integer :plan_action_id
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.time :time_open
      t.time :time_close
      t.date :dayoff
      t.string :address
      t.integer :tel
      t.string :image
      t.string :image2
      t.string :image3

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Code looks okay, what error do you get?

Comment: Please explain doesn't work?

Comment: here is an error                                                                                          undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

The issue is *probably* (can't be certain without seeing your logs) that the `plan_action` doesn't have an associated `spot` record.

To fix this, you should use some conditional logic:

```
<% @planaction.each do |action| %>
    <hr>
    <% if action.spot %>
       <%= action.spot.name %>
       <%= action.spot.description %>
       <hr>
    <% end %>

       <%= action.title %>
       <%= action.experience %>
<% end %>
```

Again, this is speculation. I wrote the answer because I felt it best to provide some sort of idea as to how to resolve it. The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I also think as Rich Peck that you don't have a record in spots table with plan_action_id corresponding to a plan action.

Following rails convention, I suggest the following:

```
class PlanAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :spot

  delegate :name, :description, to: :spot, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= action.spot_name %>
<%= action.spot_description %>
```

Finally, get your validations corrected. For example, if a plan_action should have a spot, then you need to use nested forms for both spot and plan action.